# How to pass Id with RenderAction from View that inherits PagedList<ViewModel >MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Render action that renders the Create view in pop up modal. But the Model is not allowing to pass the id of Category, and invokes error:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'categoryId' of non-nullable type 
'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Create(Int32)' in 
'PasswordCloudApp.Controllers.EntryController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type,
 a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
```

Index View:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<PasswordCloudApp.ViewModels.EntryViewModel>

@{Html.RenderAction("Create", "Entry", new { categoryId = Model.CategoryId -->
  but don't allow to access .CategoryId });}

@Html.Partial("_Entries", Model)
```

Action Method Index:

```
 public ActionResult Index(int categoryId, int page = 1)
    {
        var category = _db.Categories.Find(categoryId);

        var model =
             db.Query<Entry>()
                .OrderBy(en=>en.Id)
                .Where(en=>en.CategoryId == categoryId)
                .Select(en => new EntryViewModel
                {
                    Id = en.Id,
                    Title = en.Title,
                    Username = en.Username,
                    Password = en.Password,
                    Url = en.Url,
                    Description = en.Description,
                }).ToPagedList(page, 10);

   return View(model);
 }
```

Any suggestions how to pass CategoryId to RenderAction ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If PagedList.IPagedList is aa collection type definitely you cannot access the categoryId property.

Comment: Yes u are right PagedList.IPagedList is a collection type and definitely you cannot access the categoryId property. But any idea how to get around this and pass the categoryId?

Comment: Does the page has only one action link or several based on the categoryId?

Comment: One. I've tried also with ActionLink too, but cannot access.

Comment: If the categoryId will be same for all the values in the collection then use like,
Model.FirstorDefault().CategoryId

Comment: Thank you very much @Venkatesh N, It works just like u said, I was stuck with this problem for two days.

Comment: If its answers you could mark my answer as answered.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not populating the CategoryId in the Model.

Try:

```
public ActionResult Index(int categoryId, int page = 1)
{
   var category = _db.Categories.Find(categoryId);

   var model =
         db.Query<Entry>()
           .OrderBy(en => en.Id)
           .Where(en => en.CategoryId == categoryId)
           .Select(en => new EntryViewModel
            {
               Id = en.Id,
               CategoryId = en.CategoryId,
               Title = en.Title,
               Username = en.Username,
               Password = en.Password,
               Url = en.Url,
               Description = en.Description,
             }).ToPagedList(page, 10);

            return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @JayL for the answer, u were right about the populating the CategoryId.